# Stability of tensor product of a stable vector bundle with a line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $n\geq 1$ and $H$ be an ample divisor on $X$. Let $F$ be a vector bundle of rank $r$ on $X$ such that it is slope stable w.r.to $H$ (i.e. For every non-trivial proper subsheaf $G$ of $F$ one has $\frac{c_1(G).H^{n-1}}{\text{rk}(G)} < \frac{c_1(F).H^{n-1}}{r}$).

Then the question is as follows : Is the tensor product $F \otimes L$ for any $L$ (not necessarily effective) always slope stable with respect to $H$?

This is known for curve. My guess is that this should also be true for any smooth projective variety. I have come across some special cases where hypothesis on $F$, $L$ allow us to conclude their stability from their semistability. Is this automatically true without any conditions on them (at least for rank $2$ bundles over surfaces)?

Any argument or counterexample or any reference (I am unable to find reference of this over smooth projective varieties of any dimension) is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that $c_1(F\otimes L)=c_1(F)+\operatorname{rk}F\cdot c_1(L)$?

Comment: @Mohan, yes, using this I have shown that similar to the case of curves : every non-trivial proper subbundles of $F \otimes L$ has strictly smaller slope than $F \otimes L$. But we need to consider all nontrivial proper subsheaves of $F \otimes L$.

Comment: Also in your formula $H$ should be replaced with $H^{\dim X-1}$.

Comment: @Mohan, right, I will make the necessary edit.

Comment: The above formula is correct for your $G$ too.

Comment: @Mohan, that means it goes as follows : if $G$ is a non-trivial proper subsheaf of $F \otimes L$, then $G \otimes L^*$ is a non-trivial proper subsheaf of $F$. Then $\mu (G \otimes L^*) < \mu (F)$ gives us by the formula $\mu(G) <\mu (F \otimes L)$. Please correct me if this is wrong.